# If $(\exp(\mu_n))_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is weakly convergent, is the normalized sequence convergent as well?

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, limits-and-convergence, convolution, levy-processes

Let $E$ be a metric space and $\mathcal M(E)$ denoote the space of finite signed measures on $\mathcal B(E)$ equipped with the total variation norm $\left\|\;\cdot\;\right\|$.

> I would like to know whether we can show that if $(\mu_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is convergent with respect to the topology of [weak convergence of measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures#Weak_convergence_of_measures), then $\left(\frac{\mu_n}{\left\|\mu_n\right\|}\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is convergent as well.

This is at least true when $\mu_n$ is nonnegative for all $n\in\mathbb N$, but since the proof of this result utilizes the fact that $\left\|\mu_n\right\|=\mu_n(E)$, this doesn't seem to extend to the general case.

However, I'm especially interested in the following special case: Assume $E$ is a normed vector space and let $$\exp(\mu):=\sum_{k\in\mathbb N_0}\frac{\mu^{\ast k}}{k!},$$ where $\mu^{\ast k}$ denotes the $k$-fold convolution power, for $\mu\in\mathcal M(E)$.

> I would like to know whether we can show that if $(\exp(\mu_n))_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is convergent, then $\left(\frac{\exp(\mu_n)}{\left\|\exp(\mu_n)\right\|}\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is convergent as well.

Note that $\left\|\exp(\mu)\right\|=e^{\left\|\mu\right\|}$.

Comment: First question: Surely not. Otherwise each sequence of probability measures $(\mu_n)$ would weakly converge, since $(\mu_n/n)$ converges (the other way round).

Comment: @DieterKadelka Either you got my first assertion wrong or I don't understand your counterexample. If the $\mu_n$ are probaiblity measures, then the assertion is readily "if $(\mu_n)$ converges, then $(\mu_n)$ converges", which is trivially true and does not imply that $(\mu_n)$ is guaranteed to converge.

Comment: More complete: Let $(P_n)$ be any sequence of probability measures and $\mu_n := P_n/n$. Then $(\mu_n)$ converges, but $(P_n) := (\mu_n/\|\mu_n\|)$ in general doesn't.

Comment: @DieterKadelka Please take note of my comment below the answer of Iosif Pinelis. The reason why your counterexample works is that it does not satisfy $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left\|\mu_n\right\|\ne0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}$The answer to the second question (and hence to the first one) is no.

Indeed, let $E:=\R$.

For all odd natural $n$, let $\mu_n:=\mu$, where $\mu$ is the uniform distribution on the interval $[2,3]$, so that $\mu_n(dx)=\mu(dx)=1(2\le x\le3)\,dx$, $\exp^*(\mu_n)=\exp^*(\mu)$, $\|\exp^*(\mu_n)\|=\|\exp^*(\mu)\|=e$, whence
$$\frac{\exp^*(\mu_{2k+1})}{\|\exp^*(\mu_{2k+1})\|}=\frac{\exp^*(\mu)}e\to\frac{\exp^*(\mu)}e;$$
everywhere here, the convergence is for (natural) $k\to\infty$. In particular, letting
$$\nu_n:=\frac{\exp^*(\mu_n)}{\|\exp^*(\mu_n)\|}\quad\text{and}\quad 
\nu:=\frac{\exp^*(\mu)}{\|\exp^*(\mu)\|}=\frac{\exp^*(\mu)}e,\tag{0}$$
we have
$$\int1\,d\nu_{2k+1}=1\to1.\tag{1}$$

For all even natural $n$, let $\mu_n(dx):=\mu(dx)(1+2\pi\cos nx)$. Then, by the Riemann–Lebesgue lemma, $\mu_{2k}\to\mu$. Hence, by dominated convergence or using characteristic functions,
$$\exp^*(\mu_{2k})\to\exp^*(\mu);$$
in particular,
$$\int1\,d\exp^*(\mu_{2k})\to\int1\,d\exp^*(\mu)=e.\tag{2}$$
On the other hand,
$$\|\mu_{2k}\|=\int_2^3 dx\,|1+2\pi\cos 2kx|\ge\int_2^3 dx\,(2\pi|\cos 2kx|-1)\to3.$$
The crucial point is that, for each $j\in\{0\}\cup\{2,3,\dots\}$, the support set of the measure $|\mu_{2k}|$ (which is the interval $[2,3]$) is disjoint from the support set of the measure $|\mu_{2k}|^{*j}$ (which is the interval $[2j,3j]$). Therefore,
$$\liminf_k\|\exp^*(\mu_{2k})\|\ge\liminf_k\|\mu_{2k}\|\ge3$$
and hence, in view of (2),
$$\limsup_k\int1\,d\nu_{2k}
=\limsup_k\frac{\int1\,d\exp^*(\mu_{2k})}{\|\exp^*(\mu_{2k})\|}
\le\frac e3<1.$$

Thus, in view of (0) and (1), the sequence
$$\Big(\frac{\exp^*(\mu_n)}{\|\exp^*(\mu_n)\|}\Big)$$
does not converge, even though $\exp^*(\mu_n)\to\exp^*(\mu)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. (a) Your "$\exp^\ast$" is simply my "$\exp$" or is there a difference? (b) Does the converge implication fail to hold as well?

Comment: Regarding (b): This implication should generally hold. If $\mu_t$ is a net of finite signed measures such that $\mu_t/\left\|\mu_t\right\|$ weakly converges to $\mu$ and we additionally assume that $\left\|\mu_t\right\|\to a\ne 0$, then $\mu_tf=\left\|\mu_t\right\|\frac{\mu_t}{\left\|\mu_t\right\|}\to a\mu f$ for all $f\in C_b(E)$. Thus $\mu_t\to a\mu$.

Comment: @0xbadf00d : (a) Yes, my $\exp^*(\mu)$ (showing that the exponentiation is convolutional) is your $\exp(\mu)$. (b) What do you mean by "converge implication"? If by this you mean "converse implication", I think it is better to ask this additional question in a separate post. Generally, I think multiple questions in one post should be avoided.

Comment: (b) Yes, sorry, that was a typo. I've meant "converse implication". I've provided an answer for this implication in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3968321/47771). Please let me know whether you agree or not.

Comment: @0xbadf00d : That seems fine.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. Thinking about that, don't we simply need to add the assumption $c:=\lim_{n\to\to\infty}\left\|\mu_n\right\|\ne0$ in order to conclude the implication I'm asking for in the question as well? Indeed, if $c\ne0$ and $\mu_n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\mu$ weakly, then it obviously holds $$\frac{\mu_n}{\left\|\mu_n\right\|}f\to\frac\mu cf$$ for all $f\in C_b(E)$, i.e. $\frac{\mu_n}{\left\|\mu_n\right\|}\to\frac\mu c$ weakly. In conclusion, as long as $c\ne0$, weak convergence of $\mu_n$ and $\mu_n/\left\|\mu_n\right\|$ are equivalent. Am I missing something?

Comment: Am I missing something? Since the $\nu_n$ in your counterexample is a probability measure, something would be wrong in your post ...

Comment: @0xbadf00d : In my example, $\|\mu_n\|$ does not converge. But, of course, you are (and everyone is) welcome to find a mistake there.

Comment: Ah, I've mistakenly looked at $\left\|\nu_n\right\|=1$. So, that convergence is what we need to assume. Then the equivalence should hold. Do you agree?

Comment: @0xbadf00d : I am not sure about this, but my guess would be that that would not suffice. However, it would be much harder to construct a counterexample with that additional condition. I suggest you post that as a separate question.

Comment: Didn't I already proven the equivalence? One direction is given in my comment above. And the other direction is given in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3968321/47771). Is there any step in these proofs which is not clear to you or which you think is not justified? If so, I'll ask a separate question. Please let me know.

Comment: Please take note of my answer: https://mathoverflow.net/a/380160/91890.

Answer (score 0):

Let $E$ be a metric space.

> **Lemma 1**: Let $(\mu_t)_{t\in I}$ be a net in $\mathcal M(E)$ with $$c:=\lim_{t\in I}\left\|\mu_t\right\|\ne0\tag2$$ and $$\nu_t:=\frac{\mu_t}{\left\|\mu_t\right\|}\;\;\;\text{for }t\in I.$$ Then,
>
> 1. $\exists\mu\in\mathcal M(E)$ with $(\mu_t)_{t\in I}\to\mu$ weakly;
> 2. $\exists\nu\in\mathcal M(E)$ with $(\nu_t)_{t\in I}\to\nu$ weakly
>
> are equivalent. In that case, $$\nu=\frac\mu c.\tag2$$

*Proof*: "$\Rightarrow$": $(\mu_t)_{t\in I}\to\mu$ weakly $\Rightarrow$ $$\nu_tf=\frac1{\underbrace{\left\|\mu_t\right\|}_{\to\:c}}\underbrace{\mu_tf}_{\to\:\mu f}\xrightarrow{t\in I}\frac\mu cf\;\;\;\text{for all }f\in C_b(E)\tag3.$$

"$\Leftarrow$": $(\nu_t)_{t\in I}\to\nu$ weakly $\Rightarrow$ $$\mu_tf=\underbrace{\left\|\mu_t\right\|}_{\to\:c}\underbrace{\nu_tf}_{\to\:\nu f}\xrightarrow{t\in I}c\nu f\;\;\;\text{for all }f\in C_b(E).\tag4$$

---

Now assume $(E,d)$ is a metric $\mathbb R$-vector space and let $$\operatorname{CPoi}(\lambda):=\frac{\operatorname{exp}(\lambda)}{\left\|\operatorname{exp}(\lambda)\right\|}\;\;\;\text{for }\lambda\in\mathcal M(E).$$

> **Corollary 2**: Let $(\lambda_t)_{t\in I}\subseteq\mathcal M(E)$. If $(\left\|\lambda_t\right\|)_{t\in I}$ is convergent and $$\alpha:=\lim_{t\in I}\left\|\lambda_t\right\|,$$ then
>
> 1. $\exists\mu\in\mathcal M(E)$ with $(\operatorname{exp}(\lambda_t))_{t\in I}\to\mu$ weakly;
> 2. $\exists\nu\in\mathcal M(E)$ with $(\operatorname{CPoi}(\lambda))_{t\in I}\to\nu$ weakly
>
> are equivalent. In that case, $$\nu=\frac\mu{e^\alpha}.\tag5$$

*Proof*: Let $$\mu_t:=\operatorname{exp}(\lambda_t)$$ and $$\nu_t:=\operatorname{CPoi}(\lambda_t)=\frac{\mu_t}{\left\|\mu_t\right\|}$$ for $t\in I$. By definition of $\alpha$, $$c:=\lim_{t\in I}\left\|\mu_t\right\|=\lim_{t\in I}e^{\left\|\lambda_t\right\|}=e^\alpha>0\tag6$$ and hence the claim follows readily from Lemma 1.

Comment: What is your assumption about $E$? And in 2, a $t$ is missing.

Comment: How do you explain/prove the second equality in (6)?

Comment: @DieterKadelka Thank's for noting. I've forgotten to add the assumptions. Edited now.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Do you really mean the second ($\lim_{t\in I}e^{\left\|\lambda_t\right\|}=e^\alpha$) or the first ($\lim_{t\in I}\left\|\mu_t\right\|=\lim_{t\in I}e^{\left\|\lambda_t\right\|}$) equality? The second is simply the continuity of the exponential function together with the convergence of $\left\|\lambda_t\right\|$ to $\alpha$, which holds by assumption.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Regarding the first equality: I need to admit that I need to justify it in the case of a general signed measure, but at least in the case of a nonnegative finite measure $\eta$ on $\mathcal B(E)$ it clearly holds $$\left\|\exp(\eta)\right\|=\exp(\eta)(E)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\eta^{\ast k}(G)}{k!}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\eta(G)^k}{k!}=e^{\eta(G)}=e^{\left\|\eta\right\|}.$$ Do you think this identity doesn't continue to hold for a general finite signed measure $\eta$?

Comment: @0xbadf00d : A negative answer, even with $\|\mu_n\|\to c\in(0,\infty)$, is now given at https://mathoverflow.net/a/380258/36721

Comment: @IosifPinelis Thank you for your effort. I need to check your counterexample, but just to be sure: You're *not* claiming that *Lemma 1* above is wrong, right? And in *Corollary 2*, the only thing which then can be wrong is $(9)$. And if we explicitly assume that $c$ in *Corollary 2* is positive, the result should be correct. Do you agree? I guess the $c$ in your example is $0$, right? $(9)$ is easily seen to be correct in the case of nonnegative measures as I wrote in my comment above.

Comment: @IosifPinelis So, if you are right, my formula for the total variation norm of $\exp(\eta)$ is wrong for signed finite measures $\eta$. What's the correct identity then?

Comment: @0xbadf00d : (i) Your Lemma 1 is obviously true. (ii) I do not know what you mean by (9), but your Corollary 2 is false, as follows from the answer at https://mathoverflow.net/a/380258/36721 . Also, the supposed limit in (6) that you denoted by $c$ does not exist in the example at https://mathoverflow.net/a/380258/36721 . (iii) As follows from that same example, for signed measures $\eta$, $\|\exp^*(\eta)\|$ cannot be expressed in terms of $\|\eta\|$. This also makes it unlikely for any simple "correct identity" for $\|\exp^*(\eta)\|$ to exist.

Comment: @0xbadf00d : Also, once again, if you have more questions, please post them separately.

Comment: @IosifPinelis What I meant was that Corollary 2 becomes true if we replace the assumption that $(\left\|\lambda_t\right\|)_{t\in I}$ is convergent by the assumption that $(\left\|\mu_t\right\|)_{t\in I}$ is convergent and its limit is nonzero. On the other hand, if each $\lambda_t$ is nonnegative, then Corollary 2 holds as stated in my post. I would like to know whether you agree to this two claims.

Comment: Yes, I agree with the your latter claims.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Just noticed that you didn't reply to my question whether you think $\left\|\exp(\eta)\right\|=e^{\left\|\eta\right\|}$ holds for arbitrary signed measures as well. Do you still have doubts or even a counterexample?

Comment: @0xbadf00d : As I wrote before, a counterexample to that was given at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/380257/if-signed-measures-mu-n-are-such-that-mu-n-to-mu-and-mu-n-to-c-in0/380258#380258 (where $\|\exp^*(\rho_n)\|<e^{\|\rho_n\|}$).